# Creating Tableau WDC from associative array

Tags: javascript, json, tableau-api

I am creating a Tableau Web Data Connector as described in their *Getting Started* guide **[HERE](https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_tutorial)**.

I have implemented a similar solution previous with data from a basic associative array, but I am having trouble with my current API call.

I make an API call to an external web service that returns a JSON similar to the one listed below (simplified version)(**COMMENT** simply added for clarity and not part of original code).

```
{
    "status": true,
    "employee": {
        "id": 123
    },
    "company": {
        "id": 123
    },
    "job": {
        "id": 123,
        "job_workflows": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Start",
            "action_value_entered": "Start"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Date",
            "action_value_entered": "2017-09-11"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Crew",
            "action_value_entered": "Crew 3"
        },
        **COMMENT** - 17 other unique fields - omitted for brevity
        ]
    }
}
```

For my requirements, I need to create a new column for each of my JSON ***job_workflows*** to display the data in Tableau. I.e.

- Column 1 Header = Start
- Column 1 value = Start
- Column 2 Header = Date Complete
- Column 2 value = 2017-09-11

Etc.

My Tableau JavaScript file looks as below:

```
(function () {
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    myConnector.init = function(initCallback) {
        initCallback();
        tableau.submit();
    };

    myConnector.getSchema = function (schemaCallback) {
        var cols = [
            { id : "start", alias : "Start", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string },
            { id : "date", alias : "Date", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.datetime },
            { id : "crew", alias : "Crew", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string }
        ];

        var tableInfo = {
            id : "myData",
            alias : "My Data",
            columns : cols
        };

        schemaCallback([tableInfo]);
    };

    myConnector.getData = function (table, doneCallback) {
    $.getJSON("http://some/api/call/data.php", function(response) {
            var resp = response; // Response is JSON as described above
            var tableData = []; 

            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                // not working
                tableData.push({
                    "start": resp.job.job_workflows[i].action_value_entered,
                    "date": resp.job.job_workflows[i].action_value_entered,
                    "crew": resp.job.job_workflows[i].action_value_entered
                });
            }

            table.appendRows(tableData);
            doneCallback();
        });
    };

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
})();
```

How do I iterate over the JSON ***job_workflow*** and assign each ***action_value_entered*** to be a ***id*** in my ***getSchema()*** function? My current version simply *hangs* and no values are returned. NO error or warnings thrown.

Comment: Have you tried adding a log in the very first line of your IIFE just to make sure that it is running?

Comment: Yes I have done this and confirmed the function is fired. Logs fire on my getSchema as well as for loop in getData.